# Golang append string in string slice

Tags: string, go, concatenation, slice

How to append string in a string sclice?
I tried

```
s := make([]string, 1, 4)
s[0] = "filename"
s[0] := append(s[0], "dd")
```

But it is not correct. Then I tried

```
s[:1] := append(s[:1], "dd")
```

But it is not correct either.

How can I append a string to `s[0]`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The builtin [`append()`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#append) function is for appending elements to a slice. If you want to append a `string` to a `string`, simply use the concatenation `+`. And if you want to store the result at the 0th index, simply assign the result to it:

```
s[0] = s[0] + "dd"
```

Or short:

```
s[0] += "dd"
```

Note also that you don't have to (can't) use `:=` which is a [short variable declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations), since your `s` slice already exists.

`fmt.Println(s)` output:

```
[filenamedd]
```

If you want to append to the slice and not to the first element, then write:

```
s = append(s, "dd")
```

`fmt.Println(s)` output (continuing the previous example):

```
[filenamedd dd]
```

Try these on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/H7hfSg7rYM).